# Adding new shard - Azure Elastics Scale

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I was facing trouble creating a new shard for our system. I have an already sharded database, with two shards.

0-280000
280000-inf

I am using the [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/#download-and-run-the-sample-app) application provided by Microsoft.

Using the above app I select add shard and when I try to add a new shard and input 400000 as the new high key, performs the operations and at the very end when it tries to add range mapping, I am getting the following error.

**ERROR**

> {"Mapping referencing shard '[DataSource=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Database=xxxxxx]' in the shard map 'UserID' cannot be added because
>   the Range it covers is already mapped by another mapping. Error
>   occurred while executing stored procedure
>   '__ShardManagement.spBulkOperationShardMappingsGlobalBegin' for
>   operation 'AddRangeMapping'. This can occur if another concurrent user
>   has already added a mapping covering the given Range."}

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your second shard is actually 280000-inf, with inf meaning infinity then the error you are receiving is correct. The second shard already contains mappings for 400000. Instead of adding a shard, you need to split the second shard. Check out the [split-merge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-overview-split-and-merge/) tool instead.

Comment: Removed my previous comment. Yes, that was the problem you mentioned. I updated the Max value in __shardmanagement.ShardMappingsGlobal and __shardmanagement.ShardMappingsLocal. Then I tried to run the app and it completed all the steps successfully.

Comment: The Split-Merge tool is the correct approach if you already have data in the the shard in that range which needs to be moved - the primary purpose of the Split-Merge tool is to move data. If no data needs to be moved then you can just use the `RangeShardMap.SplitMapping` method to split the mapping https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn823939.aspx